# Renaming Multiple Files in Subdirectories

Tags: batch-file, batch-rename

Long story short, I accidentally wiped my HDD the other day while trying to install a new SSD. I used a great program to undelete my partition; however, all the files were given an .efs extension. I am currently using:

```
:begin
RENAME *.extension.efs *.
```

I have tons of lines written for each file type, and this command works flawlessly. The only problem is that I have to manually paste this .bat into every folder and execute it in order for it to work.

Is there a way I can make it so when I run this .bat, it will go through all folders and subdirectories from a central directory? I'm anal about organization so all my music, albums, videos, TV shows, etc., are all in separate folders and it would take quite some time for me to run my original .bat from each.

Any help is appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

```
for /r /d %n in (.) do pushd "%n"&call "fullpathtoyourniftybatchfile"&popd
```

from the prompt will traverse the entire tree from wherever your current directory is.

You could also place your batch into any directory on your `path` and execute

```
for /r /d %n in (.) do pushd "%n"&call "yourniftybatchfilename"&popd
```

since windows searches the `path` for any executable it can't find in the current directory.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a script that will rename files with extension efs in the current directory and all subfolders starting at the current directory. %%i is replaced by the full path to a folder or subfolders. Line 2 is needed because the for loop only does folders and subfolders.

```
@echo off  
ren *.efs *.
for /f "tokens=* usebackq" %%i in (`dir/b/ad/s`) do (
    cd %%i
    ren *.efs *.
)
```